# Python RegEx, match words in string and get count

Tags: python, regex

I want to match a list of words with an string and get how many of the words are matched.

Now I have this:

```
import re
words = ["red", "blue"]
exactMatch = re.compile(r'\b%s\b' % '\\b|\\b'.join(words), flags=re.IGNORECASE)
print exactMatch.search("my blue cat")
print exactMatch.search("my red car")
print exactMatch.search("my red and blue monkey")
print exactMatch.search("my yellow dog")
```

My current regex will match the first 3, but I would like to find out how many of the words in the list `words` that matches the string passed to `search`. Is this possible **without** making a new `re.compile` for each word in the list?

Or is there another way to achieve the same thing?

The reason I want to keep the number of `re.compile` to a minimum is **speed**, since in my application I have multiple word lists and about 3500 strings to search against.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you use `findall` instead of `search`, then you get a tuple as result containing all the matched words.

```
print exactMatch.findall("my blue cat")
print exactMatch.findall("my red car")
print exactMatch.findall("my red and blue monkey")
print exactMatch.findall("my yellow dog")
```

will result in

> ['blue']
>   ['red']
>   ['red', 'blue']
>   []

If you need to get the amount of matches you get them using `len()`

```
print len(exactMatch.findall("my blue cat"))
print len(exactMatch.findall("my red car"))
print len(exactMatch.findall("my red and blue monkey"))
print len(exactMatch.findall("my yellow dog"))
```

will result in

> 1
>   1
>   2
>   0

Answer (score 3):

If I got right the question, you only want to know the number of matches of blue or red in a sentence.

```
>>> exactMatch = re.compile(r'%s' % '|'.join(words), flags=re.IGNORECASE)
>>> print exactMatch.findall("my blue blue cat")
['blue', 'blue']
>>> print len(exactMatch.findall("my blue blue cat"))
2
```

You need more code if you want to test multiple colors

Answer (score 1):

Why not storing all words in a hash and iterate a lookup of every words in sentences thru a finditer

```
  words = { "red": 1 .... }
  word = re.compile(r'\b(\w+)\b')
  for i in word.finditer(sentence): 
     if words.get(i.group(1)):
       ....
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for w in words:
    if w in searchterm:
        print "found"
```

Comment: `if w in searchterm` won't work since also matches part of a word in `searchterm`