# Count regex found in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

I've been trying to figure out how to count the amount of times my regex matches in a list

```
def total_200():
    load = loadFiles() 
    for element in load:
        print(re.findall("\d{200}\s", element))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    total_200()
```

This will print

```
0
0
0
0
```

for each found value, I'm not sure why it prints 0, but what I need to find out is how to count the result I get from my for loop, I was reading and found that I should use the function `len()` I tried using it. Like so,

```
print(len(re.findall("\d{200}\s", element)))
```

[Python RegEx, match words in string and get count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7345252/python-regex-match-words-in-string-and-get-count)

**UPDATE**

This is the function I'm using to load the log file

```
def loadFiles():
    access_0 = open('apachelog.txt','r')
    line_0 = access_0.read().splitlines() #readlines() read the text line per line 
    access_0.close()
    return line_0
```

Format of the log file:

```
10.10.10.10 - - [29/Aug/2017:04:56:06 -0400] "GET /isomaster/download/ HTTP/1.1" 301 - "-" "curl/7.51.0"
```

Comment: You're missing a `)`

Comment: hahaha of course -_- but this now prints 0's instead [] it doesn't count them.@TerryA

Comment: re.findall("\d{200}\s", element) returns an empty list when no matches are found.

Comment: Just to be clear, your regex is looking for numbers that are (at least) 200 digits long, followed by a whitespace character (newline, tab, space etc.)?

Comment: Create a counter and add the counter each time len() returns a value greater than 0.

Comment: yes it's basically looking for a 200 status code in a log file, so I said a number that is 200 and has a white space after it. @TimPietzcker

Comment: the loadFiles() is a log file in a list format, you're saying that it's not finding any matches in the log file? @Abhijeetk431

Comment: if re.findall is returning empty list, that means nothing was found.

Comment: I added an update of what I'm using to load in the file @Abhijeetk431 once I call the loadFiles() in the total_200() the return value doesn't pass onto the total_200()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\d{200}
```

matches a number that is 200 digits long, not the number 200.

Try this regex:

```
print(re.findall(r"\b200\b", element)))
```

This will match `200` (and, thanks to [word boundary anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), avoid numbers like `1200`, `2000` etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Try this maybe:-

```
def loadFiles():
    access_0 = open('apachelog.txt','r')
    line_0 = access_0.read() #.splitlines() #readlines() read the text line per line 
    access_0.close()
    return line_0

def total_200():
    load = loadFiles() 
    #for element in load:
        #print(re.findall("\d{200}\s", element))
    print(load.count("200 "))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    total_200()
```

Comment: just prints out 0